# How can I convert string date number to datetime in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date-format

I have this date format that I wanna show it rightly formatted on the page:

```
var dt = "/Date(570333600000-0200)/";
```

I'm tired of try Date.parse() and variations, someone knows the best to way to achieve this?

Comment: What's your desired output for that input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a combination of milliseconds-since-The-Epoch and a timezone. ("The Epoch" is midnight, January 1st, 1970, UTC.)

First, you get the parts:

```
var str = "/Date(570333600000-0200)/";
var parts = str.match(/Date\((\d+)([\-+])(\d{2})(\d{2})/);
//                           /^^^\/^^^^^\/^^^^^\/^^^^^\
//                             |     |      |      \-- tz minutes
//                             |     |      \--------- tz hours
//                             |     \---------------- plus or minus
//                             \---------------------- raw milliseconds value
```

Now, constructing a date from the milliseconds-since-The-Epoch part is easy:

```
var msSinceTheEpoch = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
var dt = new Date(msSinceTheEpoch);
```

...**BUT** we need to handle the timezone. JavaScript's `Date` object only has UTC, and "local time". So we're best off adding the timezone to the milliseconds value before we construct the date.

I'm guessing `-0200` means "UTC minus two hours", so assuming that's true and the `-` might be a `+` (for "plus X ..."), we get this:

```
var hours = parseInt(parts[3], 10);
var minutes = parseInt(parts[4], 10);
var msOffset = ((hours * 60) + minutes) * 60 * 1000;
msSinceTheEpoch += parts[2] === "-" ? -msOffset : msOffset;
```

**Now** we can create the date:

```
var dt = new Date(msSinceTheEpoch);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/hosilofe/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/hosilofe/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

moment(new Date(1667145600000)).format("DD/MM/YYYY")